# Finding the max element in a List

Tags: python

I have to find the max element in a list while filtering out all of the items inside of it that aren't an integer or a float. So far I have this code and it seems to work except when giving the list `[1, ]`. I get an error saying that the list is empty and I can't find the max element.

```
def max_args(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return None
    for item in lst:
        if type(item) != [int or float]:
            lst.remove(item)
    return max(lst)
```

Comment: `[int or float]` is a *one-element list*, containing `int` (since types are truthy).  There is no conceivable object whose `type()` is equal to this list.  You want `isinstance(item, (int, float))`.

Comment: Also, modifying a list you are iterating over does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @jasonharper - I think that comment could be posted as the answer and should be accepted.

Comment: @Grismar, in addition to the comments, there are a few other mistakes in the code. Those should be addressed as well like the for loop with a `remove(x)` option. That's bad coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't check type like that. You need to check using `isinstance`. Also, you can't do a for loop and do `lst.remove(item)` the counter will get messed up.

I recommend you do a simple program to test it out. Here's an example for you.

```
x = [2,'c',4.0,{'d':5},[6,7],8,(9,10)]
print (x)
for i,val in enumerate (x):
    print ('value at position : ',i, 'is : ', val)
    if not (isinstance(val,int)):
            x.remove(val)
```

The above code is supposed to iterate through each element of list `x`. However, as you can see, it skips `4.0` and `[6,7]`. The reason, you removed `x[1]` and it resulted in `4.0` getting assigned to position `x[1]`. Similarly for `[6,7]` It moved one position to the left but your for loop iteration couldn't catch it.

The output of the above code will be:

```
[2, 'c', 4.0, {'d': 5}, [6, 7], 8, (9, 10)]
value at position :  0 is :  2
value at position :  1 is :  c
value at position :  2 is :  {'d': 5}
value at position :  3 is :  8
value at position :  4 is :  (9, 10)
```

Instead, your code should be as follows:

```
def max_args(lst):
    print (lst)
    i = 0

    while i < len(lst):
        if not (isinstance(lst[i], (int,float))): 
            lst.pop(i)
        else: 
            i +=1

    if len(lst) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return max(lst)

x = max_args([1,'a',3,'b',5.0])
print (x)
x = max_args([2,'c',4.0,{'d':5},[6,7],8,(9,10)])
print (x)
x = max_args(['a'])
print (x)
x = max_args([7])
print (x)
x = max_args([1,])
print (x)
x = max_args([1,2,3,4,5,6])
print (x)
```

The output will be as follows:

```
[1, 'a', 3, 'b', 5.0]
5.0
[2, 'c', 4.0, {'d': 5}, [6, 7], 8, (9, 10)]
8
['a']
None
[7]
7
[1]
1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
6
```

Answer (score 2):

short solution:

```
def max_args(arr):
   return max([item for item in arr if isinstance(item, int) or isinstance(item, float)])
```

Comment: Excellent work. It needs a bit of an improvement. This will not work if you pass an empty list or a list of strings. For example, this will fail when you send `['a','b','c','d']`

Comment: You can make minor edits to get that done.... `def max_args(lst):
    mx = [item for item in lst if isinstance(item, (int,float))]
    return max(mx) if mx else None`